# Как зафикисровать UIActivityIndicatorView в TableViewController swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, activityindicator

Мне надо отобразить `Activity Indicator` в `TableViewController`, чтобы при прокрутке была в середине экрана. `TableViewController` у меня грузиться из `XIB/NIB`

```
let activity = UIActivityIndicatorView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

  activity.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 40.0, height: 40.0)
  activity.hidesWhenStopped = true
  activity.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge
  self.view.addSubview(activity)
  activity.bringSubview(toFront: self.view)
  activity.startAnimating()
}
```

Работает и показывает но в в координатах `x:0, y:0` то есть самом верху слева. Но мне надо чтобы она была зафикирована в середине экрана когда идет прокрутка `TableView`

**XCode 8.2, Swift 3**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить строчку:

```
activity.center = view.center
```